# Automatically signed up for all Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, sign-up

One thing that I observed is that you're not automatically signed up for a Stack Exchange that you haven't sign up. My suggestion is to automatically sign them up to all Stack website (Think like Google. When you have sign up for Gmail, you already signed up too for YouTube. (Well okay, when first time visiting You Tube, you need to configure the channel name, but you got my point))

Example: I have register at Stack Overflow, why cant SE just signed up it all for other Stack website (like Programmers, RPG, Christianity, etc....)

Or maybe, the SE will automatically signed you up when you ask a question or answer for the first time on the site

Note: I'm not looking for one account for all Stack website, which of course, has been covered by OpenId, but I'm looking forward for a feature that will automatically sign me up for others website. Which is I'm suggesting.

Thanks.

Comment: That's actually one of the things I absolutely *hate* about Google.

Comment: Then we perhaps can add option when first sign-up to any Stack website?

Comment: It literally takes one more click to make an account than it takes to log in. Why is that such a big deal?

Comment: There's no way at all I want to be a member of *all those sites*. Many of them I actively, *strongly* do not want to be a member of. Plus, there's the technical limitation noted in the question this has been flagged as a duplicate of.

Comment: So you want people that sign up for the [Islam SE site](http://islam.stackexchange.com/) to automatically be members of [Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/) and [Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/) too? That'll go down well.  And why would a [Bike repair expert](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) automatically want to be signed up for, say [Poker.SE](http://poker.stackexchange.com/)? This just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Forgetting the technical aspects of the suggestion, I can't even imagine this being useful to anyone. And it would create a *lot* of noise, in that there would be *thousands* of inactive users across the bulk of the sites on the network, from Stack Overflow signups, alone.

Why should such accounts exist at all? That would be very distracting to the user themselves, and users on the sites in question - to say nothing of moderators on those sites.

We really don't want users created simply for the benefit of having users. We want people who think they might be active to create an account; which takes a couple mouse clicks, once you have a main account set up.